During Android Data Transfer, why Wi-Fi may be disconnected, and why turning it back on may stop or delay the transfer?
Last night, I was setting up data transfer from my wife's OnePlus 7 to Pixel 8.
After the usual process of Bluetooth enabling and scanning the QR code, the data transfer started. After a while, I noticed this warning on OnePlus 7:


This device may be disconnected from Wi-Fi temporarily. If you turn it back on, your transfer may stop or take longer.

This is very confusing and counter-intuitive to me. From what I understand, Bluetooth is for enabling device identification (including QR), and subsequent data transfer is through Wi-Fi (both devices are on the same network).
Why should data transfer stop or take unduly long, if Wi-Fi is re-connected (and why should it be disconnected?)?
I have a fairly stable connection at home, if that matters.

To be honest, I'm curious about the wording "disconnected" and "turn it back on." The former implies that Wi-Fi is still on but not connected to any device, while the latter implies that it is completely turned off...

Most likely because Bluetooth is only used for the initial connect. Bluetooth is way slower than Wifi, thus migration of a lot of data may take hours. I assume in background a Wifi direct connection is established (or AFAIR there are Bluetooth modes available that make use Wifi). And if you establish an additional Wifi connection the Wifi chip has to switch between two frequencies which mal slow down the data transfer.

@AndrewT. Good catch. I guess the answer lies inn that ambiguity and the distinction or reason is not well drafted in the warning.

@beeshyams Found it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_3.0_+_HS "high data rate traffic is carried over a colocated 802.11 link." - and 802.11 means Wifi. Later his was standardized as "802.11 PAL".

The wording here is confusing, but what really happens is that the process uses Wi-Fi Direct to establish WiFi connection between two devices directly (to avoid bad residental wifis, firewalled corporate wifis and plethora of other issues).
On most devices this means that they need to disconnect from current wifi access point (that is: your home wifi) and connect to the other device directly. As a result, the WiFi symbol can flicker and disappear and the UI status will show a different name of wifi network during that time.
If you go to WiFi Settings during that time and reconnect to your home WiFi, you'll interrupt this process.
So what the UI is actually telling you is:

If you force your phone to reconnect back to your home WiFi, you'll
most likely break the direct WiFi connection between the phones and
that (depending on quality of your home wifi and configuration) may
take much longer than copying data directly from device to device. Or fail alltogether. Don't touch it.


Makes sense, thanks.. wish I had checked that it not Wi-Fi Direct and not home network
